# The sufficient condition for the existence of poles of algebraic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Given $P(x,y)=0$, where $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial,and we get the function $y=f(x),P(x,y)=0$, then what is the sufficient condition for the existence of poles of algebraic function $f(x)$? what is the sufficient and necessary condition for poles of $f(x)$, if it is  possible to give necessary condition.

Furthermore, could we know the number of poles by any algorithm?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you're asking. Perhaps you should try to reword it with more verbs?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Thank your for you comment, I have rephrased it.

Comment: It is still unclear, I'm afraid. A polynomial _never_ has any poles.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thank you again for your comment, and I have reworded the post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, your question boils down to the following: take the closure of the curve described by $P(x,y)$ (which we think of as "the graph of $y = f(x)$") in $\mathbb{A}^1_{x} \times \mathbb{P}^1_y$, and intersect it with the $y = \infty$ line.

Algebraically, this boils down to writing $P(x,y) = g_0(x) + g_1(x) y + \cdots + g_n(x)y^n$, and looking for the zeros of $g_n(x)$.

(Formally, we would homogenize $P(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ only, obtaining $\tilde P = g_0(x) Y_1^n + g_1(x)Y_0 Y_1^{n-1} + \cdots + g_n(x) Y_0^n$. Then we intersect with the line $y=\infty$ by setting $Y_1 = 0, Y_0 = 1$, which kills everything except $g_n(x)$.)

Note: if you are also interested in the behavior of $y = f(x)$ as $x\to \infty$, then conduct the above procedure in $\mathbb{P}^1_{x} \times \mathbb{P}^1_y$ instead, i.e. homogenize $g_n(x)$ and consider what happens to it as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have to consider your answer carefully, but let me vote it up first

Comment: Yes, It is answer. So the number of poles is the degree of $g_n(x)$, thank you.

Comment: $y= x+x^2+2x^3+5x^4+14x^5+\dots$ satisfies $P(x,y)= y^2-y+x=0$, according to your method, $y$ has no poles or just one at $x \rightarrow \infty$. obviously,$y$ has pole with $x \leq 1$, why?

Comment: What is the pole? Isn't $y = 1/2 \pm 1/2\sqrt{1 - 4x}$ in that case? It has a singularity at $x = 1/4$, but the singularity is not a pole.

Comment: Thank you, I have to think again about my original question which motives the question of the post.